# Why my python code think i was trying to concatenate <int> to <str> while actually i wasn't?

Tags: python, arrays, string, concatenation, typeerror

I was trying to create a function timeConversion that take 12-hour time format as an input and return 24-hour time format. The input is a string containing time in 12-hour format i.e `hh:mm:ssAM`, `hh:mm:ssPM`. The `hh`, `mm`, `ss` represent hour, minute, and second respectively.

The full code :

```
def timeConversion(s):
     s = list(s)
     if s[-2:] == 'AM':  
        if s[:2] == ['1', '2']:
            s[0] = 0
            s[1] = 0
     else  :
        if s[:2] != ['1', '2']:
            s[0] = (int(s[0])*10 + int(s[1]) + 12) // 10
            s[1] = (int(s[0]+s[1]) + 12) % 10
        
      del s[-2:]
      s = ''.join(s)
      return s

x = timeConversion("07:05:45PM")
x
```

In line 10

```
s[1] = (int(s[0]+s[1]) + 12) % 10
```

I got the following error message:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

I tried using

```
type(int(s[0]+s[1]))
```

and it return int type, so what did I miss?

Comment: What does `s` contain?

Comment: Guessing you want `(int(s[0])+int(s[1]) + 12) % 10`

Comment: "i tried using ... and it return int type" - try putting that immediately before the error location, and you'll find that that throws a TypeError too. Your types aren't consistent throughout the program.

Comment: By the time you get to line 10, `s[0]` is an integer and `s[1]` is a string. So `s[0]+s[1]` gives your `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

s[1] = (int(s[0]+s[1]) + 12) % 10

You converted int(s[0]+s[1]) . If s[0] = '1' and s[1] = '2' , then it will give 12 .
But you need 3 .
So replace the line 10 with the following line..

```
s[1] = (int(s[0])+int(s[1]) + 12) % 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your list `s` contains strings, therefore

```
s[0]+s[1]
```

causes the problem. Try

```
int(s[0]) + int(s[1])
```

I see your problem.

```
int(c[0]+c[1])
```

not equals to

```
int(s[0]) + int(s[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

In these two lines,

```
s[0] = (int(s[0])*10 + int(s[1]) + 12) // 10
s[1] = (int(s[0]+s[1]) + 12) % 10
```

the result is `int` which is causing the problem.

```
def timeConversion(s):
    s = list(s)
    if s[-2:] == 'AM':  
        if s[:2] == ['1', '2']:
            s[0] = 0
            s[1] = 0
    else:
        if s[:2] != ['1', '2']:
            # change the evaluated result to str
            s[0] = str((int(s[0])*10 + int(s[1]) + 12) // 10)
            s[1] = str((int(s[0]+s[1]) + 12) % 10)
        
    del s[-2:]
    s = ''.join(s)
    return s
```

```
>>> x = timeConversion("07:05:45PM")
>>> x
'19:05:45'
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the solutions and comments i've noticed my mistakes. Allow me to provide my own solution to the problems. This solution required me to introduce an extra variable(which i try to avoid before, but failed miserably).

```
def timeConversion(s):
    s = list(s)
    if s[-2:] == ['A','M']:  
        if s[:2] == ['1', '2']:
            s[0] = 0
            s[1] = 0
    else  :
        if s[:2] != ['1', '2']:
            #introducing variable k
            k = int(s[0]+s[1]) + 12
            s[0] = str(k // 10)
            s[1] = str(k % 10)
        
    del s[-2:]
    s = ''.join(s)
    return s

x = timeConversion("07:05:45PM")
x
```

the code above output :

```
19:05:45
```